# Simple slideshow not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I am trying to have a simple HTML-Javascript slideshow for my webpage. It shows properly for first round, but after that, I get 3 seconds blank after each image.

I am also having a text above the image division, which I want to change with the image. The text also shows properly for first round, but after that, it does not show any text. The division for text is there, but no text is shown.

I have taken the code from first example from source code of [here](http://snook.ca/technical/fade/fade.html) and tried to modify it. Below are related codes.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="fadeinSpan changingTexts">
        <span>Text 1</span>
        <span>Text 2</span>
        <span>Text 3</span>
</div>

<div class="fadein changingImgsDiv changingImgsHW">
    <img src="images/img_1.jpg" class="changingImgs changingImgsHW">
    <img src="images/img_2.jpg" class="changingImgs changingImgsHW">
    <img src="images/img_3.jpg" class="changingImgs changingImgsHW">
</div>
```

EDIT #1: I also had this link to jquery in head tag. Sorry I forgot to mention.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

CSS code

```
<style>  
    .fadein { position:relative; }
    .fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }

    .fadelinks, .faderandom { position:relative;  }
    .fadelinks > *, .faderandom > * { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; display:block; }

    .multipleslides { position:relative; float:left; }
    .multipleslides > * { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; display:block; }
</style>
```

Javascript Code

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
    });
    $(function(){
        $('.fadeinSpan span:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){$('.fadeinSpan :first-child').fadeOut().next('span').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

How do I make the whole thing work properly?

EDIT #2: I have created a fiddle for it, which you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x0s9c0a7/1/).

Comment: create a fiddle please.

Comment: @amit, I have updated the question with link to the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both text & images are being appended to 'fadein', the text should go to 'fadeinSpan'

```
.appendTo('.fadeinSpan');
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bhnefzpg/)**

To have the text transition smooth (i.e. not appearing next to each other) you'll have to apply position: absolute; to the spans like so.

```
.fadeinSpan > * {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

This will make the text & images overlap however so nudge the images container down.

```
.fadein {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
}
```

I'd also suggest adding a background color to the spans so you cannot see the new ones appearing.

```
.fadeinSpan > * {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

**[Final example](http://jsfiddle.net/bhnefzpg/1/)**

Comment: One more problem though. The text transition is not so smooth. First the 'Text 2' adds before 'Text 1' and then 'Text 1' disappears. Any Idea how to make it smooth?

Comment: Yes, one sec and I'll write it up. ^_^

Comment: Thanks. The key thing to do was giving absolute position to fadein. Right?

Comment: Any elements that are fading in over each other should really be position absolute. :)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

JQuery

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/778pzpb8/)

Answer (score 0):

change css

```
.fadeinSpan span { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:10px; }
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
     $('.fadeinSpan span:gt(0)').hide();
     $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
     setInterval(function(){
         $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
         $('.fadeinSpan :first-child').fadeOut().next('span').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadeinSpan');
         //$( "div:hidden:first" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
     }, 1000);
});
```